# How could I prove the existence and uniqueness of solution for this ode?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ode:

$-u''(x)+au'(x)+bu(x)=f(x) \qquad\text{in}\; [0,1]\\$

$u'(0)=\alpha\\$

$u'(1)+u(1)=\beta$

where $a,b$ are constants, $f \in L^2([0,1])$.

How could I prove the existence and uniqueness of solution for this ode?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The most simple (but rather tedious) way is to find analytical solution to this equation. Variation of constants works perfectly in this case.

Comment: Could you give me more detail?

Comment: Sure. Suppose you know the general solution to homogeneous equation $-u'' + au' + bu = 0 $ which is linear combination of two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$: $u_{\rm gen} = C_1 u_1 (x) + C_2 u_2 (x)$. You can construct a particular solution of inhomogeneous equation by trying to find it in form $u_{\rm part} = C_1 (x) u_1 (x) + C_2 (x) u_2 (x)$. Using the standard method (it's called "Lagrange method" or "variation of parameters") you'll obtain a system of linear equations for $C'_1$ and $C'_2$. Then you just impose your conditions and solve for $C_1(0)$ and $C_2(0)$.Do you still need more details?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: What exactly details do you need? :)